# Docker: multiple mysql containers

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to run two separate mysql containers.

However, I'm able to connect only to the `client_mysql` container from the host (using the port 20001). The `server_mysql` container is listening on the port 20002 but it's refusing connection.

**What settings do I need to change to be able to connect to both mysql containers at the same time?**

---

My `docker-compose-dev.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:

  client_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: client_mysql
    ports:
      - 20001:3306
    volumes:
      - ./_data/client_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=client_database

  server_mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: server_mysql
    ports:
      - 20002:3306
    volumes:
      - ./_data/server_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=1
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=server_database
```

Output from `lsof -i -P` (filtered docker mysql ports):

```
89:com.docke 93244 petrhejda   24u  IPv6 0xd067260469a7469b      0t0  TCP *:20002 (LISTEN)
90:com.docke 93244 petrhejda   26u  IPv6 0xd067260469a73b1b      0t0  TCP *:20001 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

**My firewall was blocking the port 20002.**

*Of course checking the firewall was the first idea I got after right after posting the question. :)*